# slick carousel as menu - set initial slide on item with a specific class

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I would want to use slick carousel to show a menu with a single element and left and right arrows to scroll the various items:

my HTML:

```
<div class="menu menu--sublocalmenu">
  <div class="menu__item"><a href="pagea.html">item a </a></div>
  <div class="menu__item"><a href="pageb.html">item b </a></div>
  ...
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--active"><a href="pagen.html">item n </a></div>
  ...
  <div class="menu__item><a href="pagez.html">item z </a></div>
</div>
```

My question: how can I set the initial item of the carousel on the `menu__item--active` element?

JS code:

```
$('.menu--sublocalmenu').slick({
    dots:false,
    arrows:true,
    adaptiveHeight:true,
    infinite:false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using slick.js with the html you have provided.

Some CSS was added to easier visualize the carousel.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu menu--sublocalmenu">
        <div class="menu__item"><a href="pagea.html">item a </a></div>
        <div class="menu__item"><a href="pageb.html">item b </a></div>
        <div class="menu__item menu__item--active"><a href="pagen.html">item n </a></div>
        <div class="menu__item"><a href="pagez.html">item z </a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".menu--sublocalmenu").slick({
    dots:false,
    arrows:true,
    adaptiveHeight:true,
    infinite:false
});
```

CSS - for added style to visualize your carousel easier

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 80%;
    color: #333;
    background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
    text-align: center;
    color: #419be0;
    background: white;
}
```

[or view this working example here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5bqk68j/3805/)

Comment: I said that I want the carousel to start with the item with the "menu__item--active" class. I have been able to solve it by myself.